# Can I use the environment variable %PROGRAMDATA%?

Tags: bash, shell, windows-8, cygwin

I type:

`echo $USERPROFILE` and get `C:\Users\rob`

`echo $PROGRAMFILES` and get `C:\Program Files (x86)`

`echo $PROGRAMDATA` and get nothing.

Under windows `%PROGRAMDATA%` evaluates to `C:\ProgramData`

Why are some windows environment variables supported and not others, or am I just doing something wrong here? If not, is there a list somewhere of which ones are converted for use under cygwin?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is mixed case

```sh
$ set | grep -i programdata
ALLUSERSPROFILE='C:\ProgramData'
ProgramData='C:\ProgramData'

$ echo $ProgramData
C:\ProgramData
```